# Piecewise-linear Continuations vs Marching Squares/Cubes

Tags: algorithms, visualization, rootfinding

It seems that both [piecewise-linear continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise_linear_continuation) and [marching squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares) are methods to produce iso-contours of a scalar function given the function's values on a grid. It seems that piecwise-linear continuation works for any triangular mesh, not just a grid.  Marching squares also has a variation which works on triangles.

My questions are:

1. What is the connection between these methods?
2. They both seem to use linear interpolation to position the contour at the edges of the grid. Are the two methods equivalent under some conditions?